# Old supervisor not responding to email for reference

Tags: advisor, recommendation-letter, email, supervision

I have worked with my old advisor for 1+ year to produce my senior thesis. I'd say that our relationship was good when I left to do my masters (and he did write me a reference the first time around). I'd say he was satisfied with my studies if not terribly impressed.

I was fairly confident that he would write a letter this time around for my PhD application (1 year after our departure) but now I've sent him two emails without getting a reply. I feel that there is really no reason he would decline other than he is too busy or getting too many letter requests--this may be why he just didn't reply to my email without an outright refusal.

I cannot "ambush" him in person since my visa has expired. I do have contact info to one of his phd students and his phone number. Should I call him or contact his PhD student? Or keep sending more emails? What should I say in the emails? I really need his reference.

Comment: Try to call him, at least he should tell you explicitly he doesn't want to write a reference. (Your mail may have ended up in a spam folder, or he is on vacation or ill or something).

Comment: I agree you should call if he has not responded after a reasonable time (say a week or two).  If you cannot reach him, contact the department administrative staff, or the chair, and ask if they know of some reason why he is unreachable.  Do not contact the PhD student, they are not the professor's secretary and it is not their job to help people get in touch with him.

Comment: I think the answer of Bob Brown at the link cited by @NateEldredge is especially useful. Note that the professor may not remember you as he may have had a hundred or so other students since you last had contact with him and his focus has been there, and likely on grad students as well.